# Email router's error occured when send a letter by usual user of CRM 2011

Tags: email, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I couldn't get why the email-router works as well.
I'm trying to turn a settings of email-distribution for all users in CRM 2011.
I managed to configure email-router for system administrator as well but when I try to send a letter with use user's account it doesn't work

In Event log I got two type of errors:

1. The E-mail Router service could not process a provider work item using assembly
2. The access credentials that you have specified have insufficient delegate permissions to send the e-mail message. Contact your Microsoft Exchange administrator to grant the required permissions.

Well, however test access in email router runs without any error.

Does anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everyone =) 
Eventially, Instructions that are written there help 
http://www.interactivewebs.com/blog/index.php/server-tips/crm-2011-email-router-setup-and-settings/

Also, Like this article "CRM 2011 Email Router Problems–She’s a Fickle Bitch
", about how to solve some problems with email router

http://www.interactivewebs.com/blog/index.php/server-tips/crm-2011-email-router-problemsshes-a-fickle-bitch/

P.S. It relatives to CRM 2011 Email Router Problems!